# Invalid argument "class_mode" passed to

Tags: theano, keras

[root@tel-sz01-test-xxx-001 keras]#/appcom/python/anaconda2/bin/python cnn.py
File
 "/appcom/python/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Keras-2.0.2-py2.7.egg/keras/backend/theano_backend.py",
 line 1131, in function
     raise ValueError(msg) ValueError: Invalid argument "class_mode" passed to K.function

Answer (score 2):

try removing `class_mode` from `model.compile()`. This is deprecated in the newer versions of Keras.